# Implementation of Uniform Recursive Tree Java

Tags: java, tree

I was able to find implementations for so many Trees such as,

http://sujitpal.blogspot.com/2006/05/java-data-structure-generic-tree.html

and now I am in search for implementation of **Uniform Recursive Tree** in Java. This paper explains details on Uniform Recursive Tree. 
http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0022247X05004191

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: No implementation as far as I can see; you would have to roll your own.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This isn't that hard to implement, actually. You basically start with an n-ary tree and all you have to do is figure out how to add a node as a child to one of the existing nodes in the tree.

For a tree with `k` nodes, a new node `k + 1` can become a child of any one of the previous `k` nodes (i.e., any of the nodes in the set `{1, 2, ..., k}`).

What you would need is a list of all nodes that currently exist in the tree. I would maintain this is a separate, internal structure within the `Tree` data-structure. Then you will have to figure out how to select one of the nodes of the tree. This is done by a probability function. I find this part to be a little unclear and that's mostly because I've forgotten a lot of my probability stuff (and I hated probability in school). But the paper does explain how you can compute the probabilities. Essentially you have a series of probability mass functions. So if you have a node `1`, and then a node `2`, node `2` will be attached to node `1` (because there is only one node for `2` to be attached to). A node `3` will be attached to node `1` with a probability of `p(2, 1)` or to node `2` with a probability of `p(2, 2)`. What you have to make sure though, is that:

```
p(k, i) >= 0
```

and:

```
sigma(p(k, i)) from i = 1 to k equals 1
```

A naive implementation would be to simply select one of the nodes randomly out of a list of existing nodes.